# How do you retrieve the value of select tags in a form (using PHP)?

Tags: php, select

```
<select class="form-control select-picker" style="width: 334px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);" data-style="btn-info">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select one URL</option>
    <option value="callboxinc.com">option.com</option>
    <option value="callboxinc.co.uk">option.co.uk</option>
    <option value="callboxinc.com.au">option.com.au</option>
    <option value="callboxinc.com.sg">option.com.sg</option>
    <option value="callboxinc.com.my">option.com.my</option>
    <option value="pointerbiz.com">option.com</option>
    <option value="chartedenergy.com">option.com</option>
    <option value="callbox-inc.com">option-inc.com</option>
    <option value="cbimaketingsolutions.com">option.com</option>
    <option value="greensealgroup.com">option.com</option>
    <option value="tecfinity.net">option.net</option>
    <option value="bpsenterprise.com">option.com</option>
    <option value="finitech.net">option.net</option>
    <option value="finitcorp.net">option.net</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a name to the select tag, include it in a form and submit it to the server.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
   <select name="site" ... (rest of your attributes here) ...>
   ... your options ...
   </select>
</form>
```

In **process.php**

```
// Display the value of the select statement as passed to PHP
echo $_POST['site'];
```

Comment: @ian yes it will be process in process.php. you can also do it in the same page as your current <select>.but it require you to reload the page for it to be processed

Comment: So the `process.php` is where all the data entered be processed, right `@tristan` ?

Comment: @ashraf-kamarudin it would really help. My gratitude is yours!